# How to determine if guest OS is suspended when running as virtual machine

Tags: centos, vmware, suspend, sleep, pm-utils

Running CentOS 7 and in need to do some network related commands when suspended and resumed by the VMWare.

Thus far all the solutions I have seen, is connected to pm-utils. But nothing appears to work - no specific log files, creating scripts under sleep.d seem to be not triggered.

The stupidest solution I have right now is to have a cron job/daemon to stash timestamp and trigger actions when period is over a certain threshold.

Comment: Did you install open-vm-tools in the guest? also related: https://github.com/vmware/open-vm-tools/issues/273

Comment: Since open-vm-tools did not perform very well (e.g. resizing full screen, clipboard copy-paste) I manually installed the tools by mounting the install directory that is supplied by the VMware application.

Comment: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2073803 : "VMware recommends using open-vm-tools redistributed by operating system vendors.". Also if this wasn't clear, these opensource tools are made (upstream) by VMware.

Comment: So you suggest that I should install open-vm-tools and the pm starts to work?